# How to add smooth transition between slides?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the code from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_quotes_slideshow
How would I add transitions between the slides?

Comment: if you are not trying to learn how to make a slide show, just use a library like https://animate.style/

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. You'd need to practically redesign your code to add transitions. The code currently shows and hides the content using `display` which is not able to be animated by CSS. You have several options. You could use `right` and `left` positioning to show and hide the elements. If you want a simpler solution, try making the box scroll, and then just use JS to scroll the element you want with [smooth scrolling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Example)

Comment: Check mine which is very simple and short here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71911511/4728084

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the code.

In the example the action of clicking on the slide changes the CSS property "display" of the slide from "none" to "block".

```
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
```

Unfortunately this property does not allow to add smooth transitions.

Check out this article that explains how to create that sliding carousel effect https://css-tricks.com/css-only-carousel/

Comment: Check mine which is very simple and short here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71911511/4728084